# animation on hover for navigation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I love the animation on the navigation hover for this website but I can't find the code. Can someone help??

https://mikelevin.org/

My Nav HTML is below, I want to create CSS for a Nav like the link above.

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
  <ul id="topnav" class="topnav desktop-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/" class="inout">About</a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="/join" class="inout">Join</a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="/volunteer" class="inout">Volunteer</a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="/contact" class="inout">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The `inout` class doesn't have anything defined yet, it's just what I figured I'd name the animation class

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written no `CSS` at all and want us to write all of it?

Comment: @AndyHoffman no, I am not asking you to write it for me...I'm asking if someone can point it out in the CSS for the site I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply look at the `<a>` element, it has a `:before` pseudo-element.

The before is in position `absolute`, relative to its parent, `<a>`, with those settings, it takes 100% width and height of its parent:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Then, look at the transform properties:

```
transform: scaleX(0);
transform-origin: 50%;
```

It's like setting the width to "0", with a transform.

I haven't look at the CSS when hover on `<a>`, but i'm pretty much sure that it's something like that (on the pseudo-element):

```
transform: scaleX(1);
```

That one will simply animate the element from 0 to 100% of its original size.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with the :before element before.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome developer tools (right click element > inspect), you can inspect one of the nav items' CSS rules. For example, I looked at the `<li>` with the text of "Donate". In the styles pane you will notice that you can toggle the element's state, meaning you can manually toggle the hover state (refer to screenshot below):

[image: screenshot of style pane]

To which I see the following css displayed:

```
#main-navigation ul.nav>li {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    visibility: visible;
```

Additionally, if you look in the elements pane for the `<a>` child under this `<li>` you'll notice that it's expandable. As you can see, there's a pseudo-element, indicated by the `::before`: 
[image: screenshot of elements pane]

Click on that `::before` in the elements pane and you can bring up its css properties:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav>li:not(.btn):hover a:before, 
.navbar .navbar-nav>li:not(.btn):hover .hestia-toggle-search:before {
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
```

There's just a bit more css that is applied to the `::before` element for its non-hover state, but I'll leave you to play around with the DevTools to figure it out :)